# Network printer add Loki system settings printers

Tags: release-loki, networking, printer

I have installed Loki 64 bits a couple of days ago in my Dell Inspiron 1501.
I used Ubuntu for more than ten years, so I think I could install the network printer the same way. The problem is that the dialog box cannot allow me to browse the network to find the shared printers. I have to input the type of connection first: http, https, ipp, HP Socket. No smb share appears. What can I do?

Comment: I forgot my old post. I found the answer [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12072/unable-to-add-printer?rq=1), thank you for the remember post. Regards,