# Unable to add printer

Tags: networking, printer

I am unable to add a printer as the 'Add' button is greyed out. Its an HP Deskjet 3520 - I'd like to connect to it wirelessly.

[image]

Comment: First thing to do after installing Elementary OS check if can install your printer. If not - Install Kubuntu.

Comment: No seriously, if printer install does not work from the normal printer settings - open the web browser and paste in 'http://localhost:631' in the adress field and then use your elementary user and password to install the printer from within the CUPS browser interface.

Comment: If you don't have CUPS on your computer use 'sudo apt-get install cups' in a terminal window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Connection` field should contain the protocol and the local address of the printer, something like `socket://hostname` or `http://hostname:631/ipp/`.
There are several ways to try:

1. Use `sudo hp-setup -i` in Terminal and follow the instructions
2. Go to [CUPS](http://localhost:631) and add the printer from here
3. Find your printer's local IP or (preferably) assign a static IP (either using your router's configuration or the printer's menu) and use that in the Connection field
4. `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui && hplip-gui` and follow the instructions (also installs a lot of dependencies and requires a temporary USB connection to the printer)

Comment: What worked was adding socket://<ip-address-of-printer>

Comment: Glad it worked. Now, it is worth mentioning that using hplip-gui should also add scanning functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

To add to above since I can't comment yet... You also have to fill out the description before the 'Add' button enables. It will have example text, but I thought it would just use that, so I kept trying different things and it wasted my time for no good reason.

At the time of this writing, the minimum to trigger the 'Add' button (assuming http) is 'http://' in connection with one character in 'Description'.

I love EOS and the setup was still far easier than I've dealt with in the past, so not complaining, but to the devs - I feel like intuitiveness was overlooked a bit here. When I just see a grey 'http' and nothing else, I wonder, "well, should I just enter an IP? If not, should I have a terminating /? Does it expect the port or can I just use the ip if the protocol is specified at the beginning?" When I was trying 'ipp' it was the same; I was like, "well do I need to do ipp://(ip)? or (ip address)/ipp?" or "ipp://(ip address)/ipp?" - My point is, it definitely should not just be 'http' or 'ipp' and nothing else showing there. It should look near exactly what is expected for the end user.

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to Linux so when I finally got EOS installed I was pumped. I love the look and feel of MacOSx b/c I use but dislike Windows. And I was hoping this would work b/c I am trying to move whole house to Linux.

I ended up installing another Linux distro over EOS unfortunately because of the lack of intuitiveness and ease of installing not just the printer but a couple other apps.