# How do I download/install driver for HP Officejet 4655

Tags: drivers

I have tried unsuccessfully to download a print driver for my HP OfficeJet 4655.  "I've tried using sudo apt-get hplip" in the terminal, and I've been to hp website and haven't had any luck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a similar question [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12072/unable-to-add-printer/12073?noredirect=1#comment15362_12073). Have a look at sugestion 4. In the approved answer.